# What does figures mean in "facts & figures"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I Didn't find any figures in "facts & figures" of something, i only find is words which means facts, then What does figures mean in "facts & figures" ?

Comment: Did you look up figures in a dictionary? "a number, especially one which forms part of official statistics or relates to the financial performance of a company."

Comment: *[Facts and figures](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/facts-and-figures)* is a set phrase, regardless of the proportion of them someone may deem to be facts versus figures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figures are numerical values. A detailed analysis of 'something' will often contain words as well as numbers, so facts and **figures**

Answer (score 1):

*The Queen is 89 years old. David Cameron, the Prime Minister, is 49 years old.*

In this statement you have both *facts* and *figures*. The *figures* are 89 and 49.